# Saving select with multiple

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a select input with multiple set to true. How do i save this data the cakephp way along with validation.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input("user_id", array('multiple'=> 'checkbox' )); ?>
```

Comment: In case you don't get good answers, or don't understand the answers received, you can always add a bounty to your question, but please  don't create multiple questions for one and the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($this->data['YOUR_MODEL']['user_id'])){
    foreach ($this->data['YOUR_MODEL']['user_id'] as $single){
        $this->request->data['YOUR_MODEL']['user_id']=$single;
        $this->YOUR_MODEL->create();
        $this->YOUR_MODEL->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
else{
    $this->YOUR_MODEL->create();
    $this->YOUR_MODEL->save($this->request->data);
}
```

If its array , then save it in Loop in Database using `request->data`.Else save as it is

Comment: what about validation